# Add DATE and TIME fields to get DATETIME field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, date-arithmetic

I am trying to get a DATETIME field from a DATE and a TIME field. none of the functions in MYSQL seems useful.

Is somebody aware how to do this or that if this can even be done? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be as easy as

```
UPDATE table SET datetime_field = CONCAT(date_field, " ", time_field);
```

Answer (score 9):

Both of the other answers do not convert the date properly if use use a `TIME` of "838:00:00" which is a valid time according to the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html)

so instead you can try converting the time field to seconds and then adding them
for example:

```
date_field + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(time_field) SECOND
```

This will convert the date accordingly

Answer (score 4):

```
addtime(date_field, time_field)
```

Comment: please consider the following [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: also , are you sure that `addtime` is mysql defined function ?

Comment: Hey Hassan - I don't see why it's necessary to add anything more to my answer - people want a quick solution. Here's the mysql function documented: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: if date_field is DATE type you'll need to cast it to DATETIME first as it won't do automatic type promotion from DATE to DATETIME

Answer (score 1):

@Pekka is right.

Also you can use CONCAT_WS(seperator, val1, val2,....)

```
CONCAT_WS(' ', date_field,time_field)
```