# Mysql between time and dates

Tags: php, mysql

Hi stackoverflow masters

Today problem with making a query in mysql, my table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hala_wyplaty_promocje` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_od` date NOT NULL,
  `data_do` date NOT NULL,
  `godzina_od` time NOT NULL,
  `godzina_do` time NOT NULL,
  `stawka` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;

--
-- Zrzut danych tabeli `hala_wyplaty_promocje`
--

INSERT INTO `hala_wyplaty_promocje` (`id`, `user_id`, `data_od`, `data_do`, `godzina_od`, `godzina_do`, `stawka`) VALUES
(1, 0, '2026-07-20', '2027-08-20', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', 2.5),
(3, 0, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', 1.7),
(5, 0, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', 1.7),
(7, 126, '0000-00-00', '2021-00-00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', 3.2),
(9, 26, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', '11:15:00', '12:15:00', 0),
(11, 126, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', '11:15:00', '12:15:00', 5),
(13, 126, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', '10:00:00', '20:00:00', 7),
(15, 126, '2015-07-14', '2015-07-31', '12:00:00', '20:15:00', 8),
(17, 126, '2015-07-21', '2015-07-31', '12:00:00', '18:00:00', 12),
(19, 126, '2015-07-28', '2015-07-31', '15:00:00', '22:00:00', 22),
(21, 126, '2015-07-22', '2015-07-31', '10:00:00', '18:00:00', 0.15);
```

I want to get `stawka` value  based on : if current date/time is between `data_od+godzina_od` to `data_do+godzina_do`. for now its giving me dates or hours i dont know how to merge it .
cheers

Comment: About the merging the DATE and the TIME field the following topic should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307522/add-date-and-time-fields-to-get-datetime-field-in-mysql

Comment: Then you can use `SELECT stawka FROM hala_wyplaty_promocje WHERE NOW() BETWEEN ... AND ...`

Comment: works!! thanks i didnt thought concat function works in sql. post ur answer ill aprove it

Comment: Generally, it's a much better idea to store dates and times as a single entity.

Comment: it is but datetime picker dont work for me xd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the merging the DATE and the TIME field the following topic should help you: stackoverflow.com/questions/3307522

Then you can use SELECT stawka FROM hala_wyplaty_promocje WHERE NOW() BETWEEN ... AND ...