# MySQL - running total by multiple categories

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I want to have a running total column categorized by EmployeeID, PayDateStart, JobDate and JobTime, and my codes are the following:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, 
   PayDateStart, 
   JobDate, 
   JobTime, 
   JobNo, 
   NetHrs,
  (
  SELECT SUM(NetHrs)
  FROM   test2 t2
  WHERE  t1.EmployeeID    =  t2.EmployeeID
  AND    t1.PayDateStart >=  t2.PayDateStart
  AND    t1.PayDateStart <=  t2.JobDate
  AND    t1.JobDate      >=  t2.JobDate 

  ) AS CummNetHrs
FROM test2 t1
ORDER BY EmployeeID, PayDateStart, JobDate, JobTime;
```

It gives me the output like this:

```
EmployeeID  PayDateStart  JobDate    JobTime    JobNo     NetHrs    CummNetHrs
666         06/03/16    06/04/16    13:00:00    6651    9.44    9.44
666         06/03/16    06/05/16    09:00:00    6653    8.18    17.62
666         06/03/16    06/07/16    09:00:00    6654    9.97    27.59
666         06/03/16    06/09/16    09:00:00    6661    9.43    37.02
666         06/10/16    06/11/16    09:00:00    6662    12.69   18.84
666         06/10/16    06/11/16    10:00:00    6663    6.15    18.84
666         06/10/16    06/12/16    08:00:00    6664    5.83    24.67
666         06/10/16    06/14/16    09:00:00    6665    7.27    31.94
666         06/10/16    06/15/16    09:00:00    6666    8.48    40.42    
444         5/27/2016   5/27/2016   9:00:00     4441    9.33    9.33
444         5/27/2016   5/28/2016   8:30:00     4442    5.67    15
444         5/27/2016   5/30/2016   9:00:00     4443    9.67    24.67
444         5/27/2016   5/31/2016   9:00:00     4444    12.67   37.34
```

But for an employee who worked on the same day but multiple times, the running sum code doesn't work out - it shows the same cumulative value, even if I tried with "t1.JobTime >= t2.JobTime":

```
EmployeeID  PayDateStart    JobDate JobTime     JobNo     NetHrs    CummNetHrs                      
666        6/10/2016    6/11/2016   9:00:00     6665    12.69   18.84
666        6/10/2016    6/11/2016   10:00:00    6664    6.15    18.84
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I'm really confused about job date versus the pay date columns.  This is not a simple cumulative sum.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql

Comment: This can't really be done in a query accurately. It would be much better (and reliable) if done in the calling application.

Comment: What types are `JobDate` and `JobTime`?

Comment: JobDate - DATE; JobTime - TIME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT EmployeeID,
       PayDateStart,
       JobDate,
       JobTime,
       JobNo,
       NetHrs,
       (
           SELECT SUM( NetHrs )
           FROM test2 t2
           WHERE t1.EmployeeID   =   t2.EmployeeID
             AND t1.PayDateStart >=  t2.PayDateStart
             AND t1.PayDateStart <=  t2.JobDate
             AND ( t1.JobDate + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC( t1.JobTime ) SECOND ) >=  ( t2.JobDate + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC( t2.JobTime ) SECOND )
       ) AS CummNetHrs
FROM test2 t1
ORDER BY EmployeeID,
         PayDateStart,
         JobDate,
         JobTime;
```

To solve this problem I sought out a way of adding the `date` and `time` fields together.  I found a solution at [Add DATE and TIME fields to get DATETIME field in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307522/add-date-and-time-fields-to-get-datetime-field-in-mysql) and have modified your code in line with this solution.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: It worked out perfectly! I am more than excited to learn more about your explanation. Thank you so much.

Comment: Explanation added.